# Allow for (null) values but not the value zero

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

In a WHERE clause I wish to exclude observations for which the user-defined variable `WEIGHT` takes on the value zero but to keep observations where `WEIGHT` takes on `(null)`.
I tried to include `WEIGHT<>0` in the WHERE clause, but it also excludes the null values.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You simply want

```
WHERE (weight <> 0 OR weight IS NULL)
```

The reason for this is that NULL stands for an "unknown value", and `weight <> 0` thus evaluates to "unknown" for NULLs, which is not TRUE and hence removed from the result. You must consequently explicitely include NULLs with a second condition (`OR`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Where isnull(weight, -1) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
where weight is null or weight <> 0
```